# recompose's withPropsOnChange for inner props variable

Tags: reactjs, recompose

I wonder how can I user `withPropsOnChange` for inner variables ?
I have the object `person` which contains 2 objects inside that I want `withPropsOnChange` to run only if they (specifically changed)

```
{ name: 'dave', location: 'usa', age: 31 }
```

for this object example, I would like `withPropsOnChange` only if `name` and/or `location` was changed, so how do I do it ?

here an example of how I tried to play with it,
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xWvrLV?editors=1111
as you will see the `console.log` doe's show the update (like the son component will receive the prop change but `withPropsOnChange` won't catch it) not sure how to do it the right way.

thanks

Comment: it won't work look at the doc, the first argument supposed to be `Array<string>`